# JSON schema, oneOf validation

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

My login endpoint can have "social" logins and "user" login so the body could either look like this:

```
user: {
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  password: 'test'
}
```

Or like this:

```
authentication: {
  provider: 'facebook',
  token: 'abcd'
}
```

I want to create a JSON schema that validates either the first body, or the second body. I stumbled upon `oneOf` and this is what I have tried:

```
body: {
        oneOf: [{
          properties: {
            user: {
              type: 'object',
              required: [
                'email',
                'password'
              ],
              email: {
                type: 'string',
                format: 'email'
              },
              password: {
                type: 'string',
                minLength: 6,
                maxLength: 32
              }
            },
          }
        }, {
          properties: {
            authentication: {
              type: 'object',
              required: [
                'provider',
                'token'
              ],
              provider: {
                type: 'string',
                enum: ['facebook']
              },
              token: {
                type: 'string'
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
```

However that gives me the following error:

```
    {
        "keyword": "oneOf",
        "dataPath": ".body",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/body/oneOf",
        "params": {},
        "message": "should match exactly one schema in oneOf"
    }
```

Would be awesome if anyone can help me out with making a JSON schema setup for this. Thanks

Comment: Your schema is not even valid JSON. Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `oneOf`. Although I would use it differently.

```
 {
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
     "login": {
       "oneOf": [
         {
           "required": [
             "user"
           ]
         },
         {
           "required": [
             "authentication"
           ]
         }
       ],
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
         "user": {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
             "email": {
               "type": "string"
             },
             "password": {
               "type": "string"
             }
           }
         },
         "authentication": {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
             "email": {
               "type": "string"
             },
             "password": {
               "type": "string"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

With this, the two json are validated against the schema

```
 {
   "login": {
     "authentication": {
       "provider": "facebook",
       "token": "abcd"
     }
   }
 } 

 {
   "login": {
     "user": {
       "email": "test@gmail.com",
       "password": "test"
     }
   }
 }
```

But if you try to put both of them in one, it will not validate

```
 {
   "login": {
     "authentication": {
       "provider": "facebook",
       "token": "abcd"
     },
     "user": {
       "email": "test@gmail.com",
       "password": "test
     }
   }
 }
```